# Question on "the fabric of X" in sentences

Tags: idioms, writing, writing-style

I see a lot of sentences with "the fabric of X" in them.

For example,

- "The veteran feels trusted, respected and understood -- re-integrated into **the fabric of** his or her homeland."
- "Half a century ago, working quietly in a New Orleans laboratory, Ruth Benerito helped smooth **the fabric of** modern life"
- "A joint and concerted effort is needed to restore **the fabric of** communities..."
- "This is **the fabric of** the social contract that each generation knows..."

Why did those authors choose to include it? In other words, what effect in a literary sense does it bring? How does the meaning change without "the fabric of"?

The reason why I asked is that if I removed "the fabric of,"  the sentences seemed perfectly fine, if not more concise. I might be wrong.

Comment: *The fabric of* is a metaphor describing the close knit or seamless nature of a community or reintegration. It works, as you noted, without the emphasis, but not really as well. Smooth modern life? Hmm. Smooth the fabric of modern life? Better. But just a choice. Metaphors are exceedingly numerous and useful. They add richness to our language.

Comment: "**2.** A complex underlying structure: destroyed the very fabric of the ancient abbey during wartime bombing; needs to protect the fabric of civilized society." http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fabric

Comment: @medica *fabric* is **not** a metaphor here, it's literal. "late 15c., "building; thing made; a structure of any kind," etymonline http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fabric

Comment: According to Otto Santa Ana: 'For alternative views of nation, the FABRIC metaphor, such as "the intricate weave of American peoples into the national fabric", may be considered.' It's a figurative usage of the textile sense, not the possibly original structure sense. It's an extended metaphor. And I don't remember John Lawler having mentioned this one on ELU yet. But doubtless he has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Otto Santa Ana (Brown Tide Rising: Metaphors of Latinos in Contemporary American Public ...)

> For alternative views of nation, the FABRIC metaphor, such as 'the
>   intricate weave of American peoples into the national fabric', may be
>   considered. Textile invokes often complex warps and weaves which can
>   be associated with patterns of relations among social groups as well
>   as individuals. Fabric is also reticulated, which lends this semantic
>   domain to the social network Cloth likewise evokes wholeness and
>   inclusivity. Different threads and strands are woven together to
>   create a 'whole cloth' which is greater than the sum of its parts....

The rich tapestry of life.